How can I use jsonpath expression to access the json content inside a Window.render() method in a json document?
For example:
[
 {    
  "a": "Value1",
  "b": "Value2",
  "c": "Value1", 
  "d": "test.render({\"key1\":\"valueOne\",\"key2\":\"valueTwo\",\"key3\":\"valueThree\"})"
 }
]

So using jsonpath expression, how can I access "key2" in element d?
I have tried many combinations of "$[?(@.key2===valueTwo)]" <-- evaluates to true or false
Thanks in advance for any help offered, I really appreciate it :-)
I have tried many combinations of "$[?(@.key2===valueTwo)]" <-- evaluates to true or false

That's just a string.  It's not code.

You can't, (at least not with jsonpath alone) because the value of property "d" is just a simple string ...

Thank you ... I think I might have to parse that string as JSON and then try and extract the data I need from that...
